# Polymer.Templatize.templatize(template) vs. this._stampTemplate(template)

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

When attempting to [merge templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103943/polymer-2-dynamically-merging-templates/44235946#44235946) I had to resort to using the internal this._stampTemplate(template) function.

Can the same effect be somehow reproduced using the documented Polymer.Templatize.templatize(template) API function? The latter uses the former but it references a __dataHost property set to the template itself for binding and I have not found a documented way to override it.